# How to convert the following css line in Tailwind class names?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

The line looks like this:  `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;`

When searching all of the docs and also when using [css to tailwind converted](https://tailwind-converter.netlify.app/) I could not find the solution.

Comment: Something like `grid grid-rows-auto grid-rows-1fr`?

Comment: @JacobvanLingen nope, those classes does not work, as they do not exist in Tailwind CSS

Comment: `grid-rows-[auto,1fr]` will generate `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;`

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka seems like this also works ```auto-rows-[auto_1fr]```

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka since that is what i was originally asking for feel free to post an answer so I van accept it. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the same result without extending Tailwind CSS like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76154742/5794392)

We have to move from defining grid size explicitly like so  `grid grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;` and instead defined like this `grid-auto-rows: auto 1fr;`

In order to achieve that using Tailwind you have to use the following class name on the parent:

```
auto-rows-[auto_1fr]
```

Comment: If anyone knows where is this documented please link, here because I discovered this on my own exploring the Tailwind generated css.

Comment: Note it is also possible to use it like this grid-rows-[auto,1fr] and generate the output grid-template-rows: auto 1fr as mentioned in original thread question.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like `grid grid-flow-row auto-rows-[1fr]`

The documentation gives a example with this code for arbitary values `grid grid-flow-row auto-rows-[minmax(0,_2fr)]`

You can also try to custom a theme in tailwind.config.js.
Here is an example on how its done:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      gridAutoRows: {
        '2fr': 'minmax(0, 2fr)',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also try: `auto-rows-max-[1fr]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And congrats on your first contribution!
Thanks to your answer it inspired me to look for more and found a way. Please check it out and let me know what you think about it. It does works for me as intended >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/76154932/5794392

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `grid grid-rows-auto-1fr`?

Comment: Nope, same answer I got from ChatGPT, that class does not exists in Tailwind css.